# Telerik RadComboBox takes lot of time when doing filter in it, using LoadOnDemand mechanism

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, radcombobox

I have a RadComboBox control inside RadGrid in which Items are loaded using
**LoadOnDemand** mechanism i.e., `_ItemRequested()` event

All working fine except the 2 issues:

**1)** There is a significant lag between the time 
the end-user begins typing and when the filtered items show up. 
What I observed that the searching in RadcomboBox is done character wise
not Word wise.

**2)** Also, takes time to load data regardless of what value is set in 
ItemPerRequest property in RadComboBox when using LoadOnDemand.

The maximum items in this RadComboBox can be 20,000+ as well.

User is complaining again and again for the performance issue. Please 
someone let me know the simplest way of resolving the 2 issues.

I followed below Link (Server Side method), to achieve LoadOnDemand functionality:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx

If there is no solution to solve the 2 preformance issue then please 
let me know how to do the searching in RadComboBox, which is inside RadGrid, 
using LoadOnDemand approach on BUTTON click ?? Will this resolve the 1st 
Issue ??

Please note that I am new in Telerik. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please someone reply to my issue. Still I am stuck in this and unable to find any solution. I am having deadline to resolve it. Please I request all the experts here to help me in resolving this as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By setting `EnableItemCaching="true"` into RadComboBox, resolved the issue. But still the performance is bad at external server, where outside users access the Application.